# Почему появляется сообщение " Annotations are not supported at this language level"?

Tags: java

О каком уровне языка идет речь в сообщении?

> Annotations are not supported at this language level

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас проблема в том что в IDEA у вас выбран JDK ниже 6 версии.
Установите JDK>=1.6 и все будет работать.

### Настройки проекта

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

### Общие настройки IDE

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4):

Речь идет об уровне обратной совместимости компилятора. Используя, скажем, JDK 8 вы можете компилировать байт-код совместимый с JRE 5.0.

Если используете IntellijIDEA, зайдите в <kbd>File</kbd> -> <kbd>Project Structure</kbd> -> <kbd>Project</kbd> и задайте нужный <kbd>Project Language Level</kbd>

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]